# SpagoBI how to add parameter to report

Tags: sql, birt, spagobi

Hello I have a question.
When I want to create BIRT report with my parameter I recive page with blank list. Why this list isn't filled with values from CUSTOMER.CITY column (which is a string)?

I created parameter in Report Parameters folder.
Then connected in with my Data Set.
Modified my query which now looks like this.

```
select C."CUSTOMERNAME", C."CITY", D."YEAR", P."NAME"
from "CUSTOMER" C, "DAY" D, "PRODUCT" P, "TRANSACTIONS" T
where C."CUSTOMERID" = T."CUSTOMERID"
and D."DAYID" = T."DAYID"
and P."PRODUCTID" = T."PRODUCTID"
and C."CITY" = '?'
group by  C."CUSTOMERNAME", C."CITY", D."YEAR", P."NAME"
```

The parameter would be C."CITY". 
I will be thankfull for any advices.

Comment: remove the `'` so C."CITY" = ?

Comment: You were right I should remove the `'`  I added default parameter birt works fine, but still my list is empty when

Comment: I have to add all values manually, my parameter should know what's inside the table by itself

Comment: @LucasPG Please remove ' form the from front and end of the ? symbol and try to run your report again.

Comment: The problem is solved. You are right the ' symbol is redundant. I had to made another data set which picks values for my list. Thanks all for help :)